# JNI error at Weld Example

Tags: java, cdi, weld-se

Actually i want to create a small "Hello WOrld"-like Example of a JavaSE-Application with Weld-SE, but it seems that there is a runtime error.

Here is my class:

```
package de.mycompany.weldapp;

import java.util.List;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.bindings.Parameters;
import org.jboss.weld.environment.se.events.ContainerInitialized;

@Singleton
public class App 
{
   public void printHello(@Observes ContainerInitialized event,     @Parameters List<String> parameters) {
       System.out.println("Hello " + parameters.get(0));
   }
}
```

An here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>weldapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>weldapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-shaded</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>de.mycompany.weldapp.App</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

I have installed Java JDK 1.8.0_151 and Maven 3.5.2.
The compile-process was successful, but when i execute the created jar-file in the target-directory, i will get the following error all the time:

```
A JNI error has occurred, plase check your installation and try again.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.noClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/environment/se/events/ContainerInitialized
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(native Method)
... 
Caused by : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.weld.environment.se.events.ContainerInitialized
at java.net.URLCLassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
...
```

Is there anything that i did not mention or that i am doing wrong? Is there any dependency, that was not included?

I have installed Java, Maven and Eclipse again, but nothing helped.

Thanks a lot
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running in SE mode, you do not want to make any dependencies provided.  So remove `<scope>provided</scope>` from your `cdi-api` dependency.

Edit: I reran your test, and realized what's happening for you.  You're using the `maven-jar-plugin` to create your jAR.  I'm assuming though you want to use the shade plugin to create an uber JAR.  Here's an updated `pom.xml` you can use that seems to work (note that I also changed your main class to be the Weld start up class):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>weldapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>weldapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```